# What does "black sheep wall" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's a cheat code from [StarCraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft_(video_game)) to reveal entire map, but different from other cheat code, it's really hard to understand.

I can understand most cheat codes:

- `show me the money` - get a lot of mine and gas
- `whats mine is mine` - get some mine(a pun)
- `breath deep` - get some gas

...

So, what does "black sheep wall" really mean? Is there a story behind it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with learning English, this has to do with video game meta. Vote to close.

Comment: This question *is* about English. It's asking what the phrase "black sheep wall" means, on the analogy that most the cheat codes of Starcraft *are* based on actual English phrases. It is a reasonable expectation of the OP and hundreds of thousands of non-native speakers that the phrase means something idiomatic. It happens that it doesn't, probably; but that is not the OP's fault and I don't see this as a reason to close. We've kept open other questions asking about such things as errors, misprints,which few learners will stumble across, but this cheat code phrase is well-known.

Comment: @AlanCarmack If it was idiomatic at least there should be some results from a web search. Literally it is what it says. In the context of the meaning in a video game or other media, which is what the OP asks, it is off-topic.

Comment: @Sayakiss I have edited my answer, and one correction is that the song "Black Sheep Wall" did come before the game.... so it's possible the code alludes to the song.

Comment: @user3169 So, if I add what does "black sheep wall" means in literal, my question will be on-topic?

Comment: @user3196 I know the whole phrase is not idiomatic, but it is not off topic to ask if it is an idiomatic phrase. What the h3ll is this site for? This is a phrase found in the context of many idiomatic phrases. It is not the OP's fault that *this* entire phrase is not an idiom, although **black sheep** is.

Comment: @Sayakiss If this question gets closed, I'll edit it to make it more acceptable to the ELL community. Anyway, I've given the best answer I can give, before people started to closevote it.

Comment: @Sayakiss you're welcome... it's  perfectly legitimate to ask about any  English phrase here on this site (except perhaps song lyrics which are inherently ambiguous). The fact that it occurs as a cheat code should be no problem. A cheat code is a text. It is real world English.

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question because it could be helpful to current and future users of this community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Black sheep wall* itself  is not an idiom or saying in English like many of  the other cheat codes.

However, a  *[black sheep](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/black-sheep)* is a family member who does not live up to the parents' or family's expectations. Or one kid who "goes bad" while all the other kids do great. It could be that the *wall* lets you see all the black sheep (i. e., the aliens).

There is  a song "Black Sheep Wall" by [The Innocence Mission](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Innocence_Mission).  The  album  that the song  is on was released in mid-1989, years  before Starcraft was first released, March 1998. Some Starcraft fans say the cheat code refers to the song title. The song is, [here on YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rxYY3KuNVIU) and you can Google the lyrics yourself.

There is now a band called Black Sheep Wall that is allegedly named after the cheat code.

Comment: From the lyrics, the black sheep wall is the wall to keep "me"(a normal person) from the black sheep. And black sheep is something dangerous and we don't want to see it. So I think the Fog of War in StarCraft is the black sheep wall...

Comment: @Sayakiss Maybe. But when you use *black sheep wall* (expose entire map) you can still enable fog of war, if I understand the codes correctly. But it is definitely interesting to think about what *black sheep wall* means and that can depend on how the phrase is grammatically interpreted: is it a wall to protect from black sheep, is it a wall made  of black sheep, etc. This last part is definitely a matter of English learning and I will edit my answer later to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

How I interpret it is that "black sheep wall" is saying the black wall of fog is made of black sheep, which from the camera's perspective would look like a black mass. But black sheep don't block vision.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, HTMLPhoton. Please be aware that on this website we use proper capitals and punctuations for easier reading. It looks better, too, for text that remains online for posterity.